# Не отображается placeholder у виджета

Tags: python, django

Сделал виджет со списком выбора для категорий, прописываю плейсхолдер, он почему-то не показывается

```
class ArticlesForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Articles
    fields = ['title',
              'anons',
              'full_text',
              'date', 'category']
    widgets = {
        "title": TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Название статьи'
        }),
        "anons": Textarea(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Анонс статьи'
        }),
        "full_text": Textarea(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Текст статьи',
        }),
        "date": DateInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Дата публикации',
            'value': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
        }),
        "category": Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder' : 'Категории',
        }),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я редко пользуюсь forms. Поискав в интерене наткнулся на https://gist.github.com/rochacon/1514222 , что говорит наверное о том, что в тегах TextInput отсутвует placeholder. Не уверен. Так же в некоторых других источниках пишут, как совершить это дейтвсие по другому https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489699/how-to-add-class-id-placeholder-attributes-to-a-field-in-django-model-forms.